# JS : get a value and then return a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see below, I managed to write a js formula allowing me to retrieve the language visitors selected on my website.

At the end, I would like to go further : once the selected language has been retrieved I want the formula to return a number for each language. 
For instance if the selected language is "en" I would like the script to return a "1".

Could you please help me to improve this script ?

```
tC.internalvars.metalanguage = "";
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
   if (typeof metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") != "undefined" && metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") == "Content-Language" && typeof metas[i].getAttribute("content") != "undefined" &&  metas[i].getAttribute("content") !== "") { 
     tC.internalvars.metalanguage = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
   } 
}
```

Comment: It seems the above script has been cut : tC.internalvars.metalanguage = "";
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (typeof metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") != "undefined" && metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") == "Content-Language" && typeof metas[i].getAttribute("content") != "undefined" &&  metas[i].getAttribute("content") !== "") { 
         tC.internalvars.metalanguage = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
      } 
   }

Comment: How are you supposed to associate a number with a language?  Besides "en" being 1, how would you determine what to associate with the others?

Comment: I believe you should provide an mapping object:

var langMap = {
  'en': 1,
  'de': 2,

  // so on
}

and return mapped value:

return langMap[value] // value is your "en" string

Comment: Thanks @ЛёшаАн but can you help me to do this mapping in my script I'm not sure I know how to do it...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you find your language, you have just to stop the loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
   if (typeof metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") != "undefined" && metas[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") == "Content-Language" && typeof metas[i].getAttribute("content") != "undefined" &&  metas[i].getAttribute("content") !== "") { 
     tC.internalvars.metalanguage = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
     // now you find the language and break here
     break;
   } 
}
```

In this way you skip the other elements as you don't need any more here.

About the mapping, a quick way is to define a plain object in your main scope, that is like an hash map:

```
var languages = {
    "en": 1,
    "it": 2,
    // ... so on
}
```

So you could get the language code with:

```
var langCode = languages[tC.internalvars.metalanguage];
```

Or you could return the value from inside a function:

```
return languages[tC.internalvars.metalanguage];
```